# Should these words be hyphenated?

Tags: editing, grammar

I have the title for a map that shows point locations distributed across a beach where biologists will count the number of clams.  The claims will be harvested and used as bait in a crab fishery.  Should the title be *Bait-Clam Survey* or *Bait Clam Survey*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with "Bait-Clam Survey". Generally you hyphenate when the two or more words coming before the noun form a compound adjective. Because "bait-clam" is acting as a single adjective they should be hyphenated.

For more information on hyphenation see:
http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp